# Image is moving when I am scrolling the bar to the right

Tags: html, css

I have an image and when I go to the right this image is following me.I want to make it not move while I am scrolling on the right side.How to make this image not moving ?

```
 .img1 {
  top:9%;
 left:0%;
 height:67%;
 width:40%;
   position: fixed;

            background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/top-view-backgammon-game-board_68747-224.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg");
        }
```

the html code is this

```
<div class="img1">
 
 
 <div id='chess_board'>
 
   
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: can we see the html code?

Comment: yes i edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is the feature of `position: fixed;`, simply, remove it or just give it a position other than `fixed`.

Also, for your background image not to be repeated, you could change your whole `background-image` property to `background: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/top-view-backgammon-game-board_68747-224.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg") no-repeat;`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: fixed` and change it to `position: absolute`.

`position: fixed` makes your HTML element sticky - this may come in handy in the future if you want, say, a navigation bar to stick to the top of a page, or a footer to stick to the bottom.

You can find out more about the `position` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).